# Hours+Minutes between two Java Date objects

Tags: java, date

I have found how to get the hours between two dates and the minutes . What I want is the exact difference between both of them, this is the code that I'm using:

```
private String getHours(Message punch) {
    LocalTime out = Instant.ofEpochMilli(message.getOut().getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of(message.getTimezone()))
            .toLocalTime();
    LocalTime in = Instant.ofEpochMilli(message.getIn().getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.of(message.getTimezone()))
            .toLocalTime();
    Duration duration = Duration.between(in, out);
    Long hours = duration.toHours();
    Long minutes = duration.toMinutes() - (hours * Constants.MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR);
    return String.format("%d:%d", hours, minutes);

}
```

It works fine for the major of the cases but I'm having an error in the following case:

- message.getIn()  returns:  12:59
- message.getOut() returns:  22:00

Both are the same day, the difference that I'm expecting is 9:01, but I'm getting **-14:-59**

Debugging the code I realize that out is getting 04:00 and in is getting 18:59.

For almost all the cases it works well but It happens in some scenarios.

Comment: What happens when you switch in and out as parameters to Duration.between?

Comment: Plse check if this code helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39614758/4247543

Comment: By the way, Date has a [toInstant()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--) method.

Comment: If I change the values in the duration only change from -14:-59 to 14:59 but the difference still wrong

Comment: Explain your input data. Give exact examples of your inputs and outputs. Currently this Question does not provide enough info to form a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are using `LocalTime` class but you should be using `LocalDateTime` class. It apears that your timezone is GMT+6, so in your example your in time and out time fall in different days - your in time in the evening of a previous day and out time on the morning of the next day. But because you are using `LocalTime` you are loosing the fact that those are times in different days. Change your `LocalTime` to `LocalDateTime` and see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard, going through too many gyrations in your code.

## Use `Instant`

You have a pair of `Instant` objects but throw them away. Use them. An instant is a specific moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
Instant start = … ;
Instant stop = … ;
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

How you get your instants is a mystery. If you revise your Question to explain the exact nature of your inputs, I will provide more code here.

If you are being passed a pair of `java.util.Date` objects, convert them to `Instant`. Use new conversion methods added to the old date-time classes. No need for time zones at all for calculating elapsed time.

```
Instant start = utilDateX.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = utilDateY.toInstant() ;
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Calculating elapsed time with `LocalTime` is rarely appropriate because of crossing over into the next or previous days.